# Initializing defaults from a file, Swift differs from Obj-C?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm following the example code found [at Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/NSUserDefaultsController.html) to load up initial defaults the first time my new app runs. But I am using Swift, so the I converted the code thus:

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("InitialDefaults", ofType: "plist")
    let defaults = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:path!)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defaults)
```

Xcode complains that the API for the last line requires a string, not a dict. When I attempt to right-click the definition, it cannot find it. I cannot find any Swift API documentation on this. All the documentation and example code I *can* find is in Obj-C, and it all takes a dict.

Anyone know what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Re: right-clicking to find the definition, was Xcode still indexing the project by any chance?

Comment: Have a play around with force downcasting your defaults in `registerDefaults()`. Something like ...`registerDefaults(defaults as! [String: AnyObject])`

Comment: @caseynolan Yes, the rest of the project was indexed - with hundreds of megabytes of indexes! What is up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`registerDefaults`requires `[String : AnyObject]`. So try

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("InitialDefaults", ofType: "plist")
let defaults = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:path!) as! [String : AnyObject]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defaults)
```

More safe solution that does the same:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("InitialDefaults", ofType: "plist")
, defaults = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:path) as? [String : AnyObject]
{
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defaults)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Avt (and casey). Forgive me, but can you explain what this syntax is saying? I can see that it's saying "this is a dictionary of strings", but what does the AnyObject do in this context?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz ```AnyObject``` can represent an instance of any class type. You can read more here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html